# Jquery after nested use

Tags: jquery

I want to create following HTML:

```
<div>
   <img src="random.png">
   <input type="radio">
   <input type="radio">
</div>
```

And here is the jquery code:

```
  $("#main").append(
    $("<div>").append(
      $("<img>").after(
        $("<input>").attr({type:"radio", value:"Manmade", checked:"checked"}).after(
          $("<input>").attr({type:"radio", value:"Natural"})
        )
      )
    )
```

However only the image showed up, not the buttons. How do I fix this problem?

```
<div id="275">
    <img src="random.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Simplify your code, Whats the use of so much nesting?

Comment: `after` generally doesn't work on a single DOM node that isn't part of the DOM as there is no parent, siblings or anything else to determine where after really is, not only that but the selector still returns only the DIV, so the other elements would be lost anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`after` makes no sense here, if you want to place something after something in an append, just append it after it.

You can append multiple elements by just separating with a comma

```
$("#main").append(
    $("<div />").append(
        $("<img />"),
        $("<input />", {
            type    : "radio", 
            value   : "Manmade", 
            checked : "checked"
        }),
        $("<input />", {
            type  : "radio", 
            value : "Natural"
        })
    )
)
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/8bbwpjzt/1/)

Comment: You can use a placeholder image like this so that people can see that the image part also works: http://placehold.it/100x100

Comment: Thanks! One more question: how to make the text show up?

Comment: What text, you don't have any text ?

Comment: That's the value, it's not visible anywhere ?

Comment: Nvm, I figured it out. Thanks!